# Drop-down menu on touch based devices

Tags: html, ios, css, navigation

I have this navigation bar on my website and it doesn't drop down on my iPod touch, I suspect the same for iPhones and iPads.
[This is one of the pages](http://orhsfoundation.com/about)

I was wondering if there is any quick fix to enable the touch/hover.

[CSS](http://orhsfoundation.com/style.css)

Comment: Not related to your question, but in IE8 the top line of text, "ORHS Foundation", is covered slightly by your header.

Comment: As a side note, you should make you banner at the top of you page a lot smaller (its 9514 x 1732 at the moment)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are interested in iDevices, then you can use this trick:

```
#nav ul {
display: none;
/* Your styles */
}
#nav > li:hover ul {
display: block;
}
/* This is important */
#nav > li > a:hover {
color: #fff; /* You can set the same color or add other style.*/
}
```

If an element has the `:hover` event then the first tap iOS renders `:hover` and the second tap raises the click event.

That should work.

P.S. It's better to make different UI logic for mobile, touch and desktop.

Answer (score 3):

There's a good article on this here - http://www.nczonline.net/blog/2012/07/05/ios-has-a-hover-problem/

I'd suggest using [Modernizr](http://modernizr.com/) as it provides a no-touch CSS class you could use for touch screen devices, or you can use Javascript to detect hovers and add a class to your element.

```
if (!("ontouchstart" in document.documentElement)) {
    document.documentElement.className += " no-touch";
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The most elegant solution I've come across is by [Osvaldas Valutis](http://osvaldas.info/drop-down-navigation-responsive-and-touch-friendly)

His method involves a really tiny jQuery plugin to detect touch events on navigation list items with dropdown ul menus.

For example, you might mark up your navigation like this:

```
<nav id="nav-primary">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="/">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="/about/">About</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="/about/index.html">Dropdown item 1</a></li>
                <li><a href="/about/page.html">Dropdown item 2</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

You then call the plugin with a single line of jQuery like so:

```
$( '#nav-primary li:has(ul)' ).doubleTapToGo();
```

This ensures that the Home link in the example above still works as expected, since it doesn't have a dropdown menu. The only (very minor) drawback is that there's a little bit of redundancy in the first link on the dropdown, but that doesn't hurt.

Comment: I wonder how many people would understand that the need to double tap.  The web has taught all of us that double clicking is desktop behaviour.  and single clicking (or tapping) is web behaviour.

Comment: I believe that this technique would be very un-discoverable to most users