# Fix CSS hover on iPhone/iPad/iPod

Tags: ios, css, hover, touch

I want to fix the hover effect on iOS ( change to touch event ) but I dont have any idea .
Let me explain this .
You have a text in your page :

```
<div class="mm">hello world</div>
```

With style :

```
.mm { color:#000; padding:15px; }
.mm:hover { background:#ddd; }
```

Ok , in dekstop if you put your mouse over the text you get a #ddd background , right ?
But in iOS if you touch the text you get nothing but if you tap it it gets a ugly and sticky #ddd background which is not nice and I want the user get the hover effect when he touch that text ( something like touchevent I think ) .
But I see some websites fixed that like freemyappps.com or 
( please check this site ->[D4F](http://d4fteam.com/) on your ios device and touch something to see the hover effect like eating a cake :) )
But how these sites fixed that ? 
How can fix like them ?
Thanks

Comment: They might have used JavaScript

Comment: so How ? :( can you make a jsfiddle sample ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a basic, successful use of javascript hover on ios that I made:

Note: I used jQuery, which is hopefully ok for you.

JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  // Sorry about bad spacing. Also...this is jquery if you didn't notice allready.
  $(".mm").hover(function(){
    //On Hover - Works on ios
    $("p").hide();
  }, function(){
    //Hover Off - Hover off doesn't seem to work on iOS
    $("p").show();
 })
});
```

CSS:

```
.mm { color:#000; padding:15px; }
```

HTML:

```
<div class="mm">hello world</div>
<p>this will disappear on hover of hello world</p>
```

Comment: Could you please edit this fiddle with your solution ? http://jsfiddle.net/smmCW/1/ - sorry for being newbie ... :"(

Comment: and it is the exact same code that is in the jsfiddle and above. if you are going to use the example, don't forget to import jquery with: `<script type='text/javascript' src='//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js'></script>` or something similar

Comment: And I never updated the question with the new jsfiddle example.

Comment: No :(  I have a mistake maybe ? :(

Comment: I feel like this shouldn't be the accepted answer because the question is about *CSS* hover, and this solution is pure JavaScript.

Answer (score 118):

Add onclick="" to anything you wish iOS to recognise as an element with a hover.

```
<div onclick="">Click Me!</div>
```

Comment: This works for one of my case, another one still not works, I guess there  still something need to be clarified.

Comment: October 2019, this still works. I can't believe such a simple thing fixes the problem. Does anyone have clear explanation why it is work?

Answer (score 51):

Some people don't know about this. You can apply it on **`div:hover`** and working on iPhone .

Add the following css to the element with **`:hover`** effect

```
.mm {
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

Comment: This seems the best solution instead of adding a `onClick` to the element

Comment: trivial solution, but works! meseems iOS has a lot in the style of "if it seems to be hoverable/clickable, treat it like that".

Comment: This would be an ideal solution, except that it does not seem to work on iPad on iOS 11.

Comment: Funny you'd have to do so even on <a> tags

Comment: is it really worked for you? I have the same problem but after touch, the hover state will stuck to the element

Answer (score 27):

The onclick="" was very temperamental when I attempted using it.

Using :active css for tap events; just place this into your header:

```
<script>
    document.addEventListener("touchstart", function() {},false);
</script>
```

Comment: I am finding this crashes safari when you use long-click on the buggy iOS 9.1 ... which 0.4% of our users are still on

Comment: @Ruskin 'only', our percentage is higher and it's a year after your comment! ):

Answer (score 16):

I"m not sure if this will have a huge impact on performance but this has done the trick for me in the past:

```
var mobileHover = function () {
    $('*').on('touchstart', function () {
        $(this).trigger('hover');
    }).on('touchend', function () {
        $(this).trigger('hover');
    });
};

mobileHover();
```

Comment: Neatest, most compliant solution here imo.

Comment: This works great for me. Just tested it on iPhone. Thanks.

Answer (score 14):

## Add a tabIndex attribute to the body:

```
<body tabIndex=0 >
```

This is the only solution that also works when Javascript is disabled.

## Add `ontouchmove` to the html element:

```
<html lang=en ontouchmove >
```

For [examples and remarks see this blogpost](https://dev.webonomic.nl/fixing-the-iphone-css-hover-problem-on-ios):

Confirmed on iOS 13.

These solutions have the advantage that the hovered state disappears when you click somewhere else. Also no extra code needed in the source.

Comment: ontouchmove worked for me - do i need tabIndex too?

Comment: No, you can choose. TabIndex is the only one that works when Javacript is disabled.

Comment: The tabindex attribute is the standard way to make otherwise unresponsive HTML elements `:focus`-able and `:hover`-able. This should be the recommended answer.

Comment: Thanks for this one. All of the above fixes didnt fully work on my iPad. With this version can also unhover items .. very weird behaviour otherwise. Damn iOS!

Answer (score 5):

Here is a very slight improvement to user1387483's answer using an immediate function:

```
(function() {
  $("*").on( 'touchstart', function() {
    $(this).trigger('hover') ;
  } ).on('touchend', function() {
    $(this).trigger('hover') ;
  } ) ;
})() ;
```

Also, I agree with Boz that this appears to be the "neatest, most compliant solution".

Answer (score 4):

In response to Dan (https://stackoverflow.com/a/20048559/4298604), I would recommend a slightly altered version.

```html
<div onclick="void(0)">Click Me!</div>
```

Adding "void(0)" helps to obtain the undefined primitive value, as opposed to "".

Answer (score 2):

The hover pseudo class only functions on iOS when applied to a link tag. They do that because there is no hover on a touch device reall. It acts more like the active class. So they can't have one unless its a link going somewhere for usability reasons. Change your div to a link tag and you will have no problem.

Answer (score 2):

I know it's an old post, already answered, but I found another solution  **without adding css classes** or doing too much javascript than really needed, and I want to share it, hoping can help someone.
 
I found that to enable `:hover` effect on every kind of elements on a Touch enabled browser, you need to tell him  that your elements are **clickable**.
To do so you can simply add an empty handler to the click function with jQuery or javascript.

```
$('.need-hover').on('click', function(){ });
```

It's better if you do so only on Mobile enabled browsers with this snippet:

```
// check for css :hover supports and save in a variable
var supportsTouch = (typeof Touch == "object");

if(supportsTouch){ 
    // not supports :hover
    $('.need-hover').on('click', function(){ });
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I successfully used

```
(function(l){var i,s={touchend:function(){}};for(i in s)l.addEventListener(i,s)})(document);
```

which was documented on 
http://fofwebdesign.co.uk/template/_testing/ios-sticky-hover-fix.htm

so a variation of Andrew M answer.

Answer (score 1):

1. Assigning an event listener to the target element seems to work. (Works with 'click', at least.) [CSS hover on ios works only if an event listener is assigned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14705751/css-hover-on-ios-works-only-if-an-event-listener-is-assigned/28792519#28792519)
2. Wrapping the target element in an a[href=trivial] also seems to work. https://stackoverflow.com/a/28792519/1378390

A related note/diagram on mobile Safari's algorithm for handling clicks and other events is here: [Is it possible to force ignore the :hover pseudoclass for iPhone/iPad users?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2741816/is-it-possible-to-force-ignore-the-hover-pseudoclass-for-iphone-ipad-users)

Answer (score 0):

On some sites I need to use css "cursor:help". Only iOS it gave me a lot of irritation. To solve this, change everything af the page to "cursor:pointer". That works for me.

jQuery:

```
if (/iP(hone|od|ad)/.test(navigator.platform)) {
$("*").css({"cursor":"pointer"});
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Where, I solved this problem by adding the visibility attribute to the CSS code, it works on my [website](http://www.unifore.net)

Original code:

```css
#zo2-body-wrap .introText .images:before
{
background:rgba(136,136,136,0.7);
width:100%;
height:100%;
content:"";
position:absolute;
top:0;
opacity:0;
transition:all 0.2s ease-in-out 0s;
}
```

Fixed iOS touch code:

```css
#zo2-body-wrap .introText .images:before
{
background:rgba(136,136,136,0.7);
width:100%;
height:100%;
content:"";
position:absolute;
top:0;
visibility:hidden;
opacity:0;
transition:all 0.2s ease-in-out 0s;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Old Post I know however I successfully used onlclick="" when populating a table with JSON data.  Tried many other options / scripts etc before, nothing worked.  Will attempt this approach elsewhere.  Thanks @Dan Morris .. from 2013!

```
     function append_json(data) {
     var table=document.getElementById('gable');
     data.forEach(function(object) {
         var tr=document.createElement('tr');
         tr.innerHTML='<td onclick="">' + object.COUNTRY + '</td>' + '<td onclick="">' + object.PoD + '</td>' + '<td onclick="">' + object.BALANCE + '</td>' + '<td onclick="">' + object.DATE + '</td>';
         table.appendChild(tr);
     }
     );
```

Answer (score 0):

I know that the question is old but still relevant.

The only solution that I've found that works is using @media query like this:

```
@media (hover) { my-class:hover {
  //properties
 }
}
```

My reference: https://www.jonathanfielding.com/an-introduction-to-interaction-media-features/