# Hover menu items take 2 taps instead of 1 in order to work on iPad

Tags: jquery, ipad

[On my page](http://pizzaontime.fr/new/) I have a particular sub-menu displayed when hovering a particular main menu item ("nos restaurants"). Everything works on desktop, but on iPad this sub-menu's items take 2 taps instead of one (one tap does nothing). Why?

HTML:

```
<div class='sub_menu_wrap'>
  <div class='menu_la_carte'>
    <?php wp_nav_menu( array('menu' => 'Menu La Carte' )); ?>
  </div>
  <div class='menu_nos_restaurants'>
    <?php wp_nav_menu( array('menu' => 'Menu Nos Restaurants' )); ?>
  </div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
$( '.restaurants_li, .menu_nos_restaurants' ).hover(
  function() {
    $( '.menu_la_carte' ).fadeOut(0);
    $( '.menu_nos_restaurants' ).fadeIn(0);            
  }, function() {
    $( '.menu_la_carte' ).fadeIn(0);
    $( '.menu_nos_restaurants' ).fadeOut(0);           
  }
);
$( '.sub-menu' ).click(function(event) {
  event.stopPropagation();
});
```

Comment: if my answers helps you then please mark it as acceptable answer. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You should check this topic: [Fix CSS hover on iPhone/iPad/iPod](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18047353/fix-css-hover-on-iphone-ipad-ipod)

On touch device any element that has hover state requires 2 taps (first turns on hover state and second is like standard desktop click).

There is also a complete solution for CSS or jQuery hover elements. Look at this: [iPad/iPhone hover problem causes the user to double click a link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3038898/ipad-iphone-hover-problem-causes-the-user-to-double-click-a-link)

And another link found, may be helpful: 
https://css-tricks.com/forums/topic/ipad-hover-effect/

Comment: Thanks but if you check the page you'll see that the 2 taps I'm talking about are on top of the tap for the hover action - so it's 3 taps in total. And so your answer doesn't address my problem. In other words according to what you say "On touch device any element that has hover state requires 2 taps (first turns on hover state and second is like standard desktop click)" there should be 2 taps in total, yet there are 3 on my page: one for hover action, one that does nothing at all, and one that actually works and redirects.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is happening due to 300ms delay for mobile browsers.

**According to Google:**

> ...mobile browsers will wait approximately 300ms from the time that
>   you tap the button to fire the click event. The reason for this is
>   that the browser is waiting to see if you are actually performing a
>   double tap.

I faced same issue for one of my client project and for this I had used https://github.com/ftlabs/fastclick library for eliminating the 300ms delay between a physical tap and the firing of a click event on mobile browsers.

You can also try https://github.com/dave1010/jquery-fast-click

In same project I also faced double tap issue for dropdown menus and that was also due to 300ms delay.

Double tap issue was appearing in android browsers/devices so I detected the user agent and applied the a custom function to handle that issue this might be helpful for you.

```
<?php 
 if (user_agent() == 'android') {
    $handleClick = "onclick=\"checkClicks('$base_url/index.php')\"";
    $homePage = "#";
} else {
    $handleClick = " ";
    $homePage = "index.php";
}
?>

<!--//Script to Handle menu for mobile devices-->
<script type="text/javascript">
//handle 300ms delay click in android devices
var clicks = 0;
function checkClicks(e) {
    clicks = clicks + 1;
    if (clicks == 2) {
        window.location = e;
    } else {
        //do nothing
    }
}
</script>
```

You can also try some available plugins to handle this issue if you face.

https://github.com/dachcom-digital/jquery-doubleTapToGo

https://github.com/zenopopovici/DoubleTapToGo