# Bootstrap mobile hover

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I`ve build a [Website](http://new.brocodes.de/projekte.html) with a portfolio.

My problem is the hover-effect on a mobile phone (for example on my iPhone).

On the index.php i build an rotating card and this is working fine on mobile when clicking.

For the portfolio i`m using the following code:

```css
.tile:hover .overlay {
  opacity: 1;
}

.tile:hover p {
  top: 75%;
}

.tile:hover a {
  top: 90%;
}

.tile:hover h2 {
  bottom: 60%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container section">
  <div class="row">
    <h1>Projekt</h1>
    <div class="col-sm-6">
      <div class="tile tile_effect">
        <img src="images/background.jpeg">
        <div class="overlay">
          <h2>ILakeIt</h2>
          <p>Webdesign | Test | Test | Test Webdesign | Test | Test | Test Webdesign | Test | Test | Test</p>
          <a href="http://www.google.de">To Projekt</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I already tried to user :focus and :active but still get no hover-effect on my phone.

I can`t understand why it works on the index.html with :hover but on the other page not. Is there any solution to prevent this error?

Comment: How do you even hover on an touch-screen device?

Comment: You can't have hover effects on mobile devices. Or, rather, you can, but you physically cannot hover over the element. Instead, the hover effect is translated into a tap when using mobile/touchscreen devices.

Answer (score 0):

There is no such thing as hover on mobile devices as you know it on other devices. People have had success with workarounds such as this though [Fix CSS hover on iPhone/iPad/iPod](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18047353/fix-css-hover-on-iphone-ipad-ipod)